# Get data from a string and return it as JSON in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, string

```
NOTE : This is for a PHP script !
```

So I've been working on a program but I right now I am stuck because I can't split the data right.

I have a list with numbers just like this :

```
50.0.1 581 50.0.2 545 50.0.3 541 50.0.4 18 50.0.5 2 50.0.6 33 50.0.7 1 [...]
```

I have add that information into an ARRAY or JSON format (preferable JSON).

The main data looks like this (we take groups): 50.0.1 581 so basically I have to split 50.0.1 from 581 add it to JSON/ARRAY and then move to the next group that in our case is 50.0.2 545. (and so on)

Example JSON:

```
{"result": {
    "50.0.1": "581",
    "50.0.2": "545"
}}
```

Note : First value will always have the same format : [0-9]{2}.[0-9].[0-9] (ex : 50.0.1)

However, the second value can be 1 to 4 digit long : [0-9]{1,4}.

I am sorry if I did not make myself clear - it is quite hard to explain. Will add more example if required !

```
Thank you very much !
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own working solution : /([.\d]*)\t(\d*)/ . Will output 3 arrays. Simple combine second with third and I got what I want.

Answer (score 2):

simply explode on the spaces, e.g.

```
$arr = explode(' ', $your_string);
```

then build a new array using each pair of elements:

```
$newarr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 2) {  // note the += 2
    $newarr[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i+1];
}
echo json_encode($newarr);
```

note that this will probably trash things if any of those "key" values are duplicates.

Comment: It seem to work well so far. I will test it with different examples and get back here to add one more comment or just make it as the accepted answer. Thank you very much !

Comment: It did not add them as separate elements : http://puu.sh/1tLaM. Instead it's only one big element and then :null

Comment: looks like it's tab and carriage return separated. would've been nice if you mentioned that in the original post. so basically, explode on the `\r`, then explode each individual bit on `\t`, or since it seems to basically be csv data, use fgetcsv on the original file in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `array_chunk()` after `explode()`, and then access values in JS as `item[0]` and `item[1]` for each pair.